# Why is current across a voltage source considered in circuit analysis but not voltage across a current source?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, current-source, voltage-source

I am a beginner at circuit analysis and cannot find a good answer to this question. I know that for a current source voltage is dependent on the rest of the circuit, but the same can be said of a voltage source and current. When we do KCL we consider the current on a voltage source, but when we do KVL we do not consider voltage on a current source.

Comment: Current is not "across", it's through.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure why you think KCL concerns itself with voltages anywhere, or KVL somehow needs to know anything about current anywhere. When applying KCL, we consider *only* current. When applying KVL, we consider *only* voltage.

Often we use a combination of Ohm's law and KVL in a single step, which might give the *impression* that we are considering current during an application of KVL:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ4ZQy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To save steps in the algebra, you might write KVL applied to this loop as:

$$ V_1 - (I_3\times R_2) -V_3 = 0 $$

The term \$I_3\times R_2\$ is an application of Ohm's law mixed in with KVL. The truth is, though, that KVL in and of itself doesn't say anything more than:

$$ V_1 - V_2 -V_3 = 0 $$

There is absolutely no consideration or mention of any current anywhere in that expression.

A similar mix of laws might be used to save steps in an application of KCL. Here we know the voltage across R1, and can use that information to our advantage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foa21T.png)</sup>

KCL applied to node A, if we sneak in a cheeky application of Ohm's law, would say something like:

$$ \frac{4V}{R_2} = I_2 + I_3 $$

Again, this gives the impression that KCL somehow concerns itself with voltage, since there is a voltage term in that equation, but in reality it doesn't. KCL's only claim is that:

$$ I_1 = I_2 + I_3 $$

This is regardless of R1, or the voltage across it, or R2, or V3 or anything else.

Comment: RE "When applying KCL, we consider only current.", Typically the next step is to write the currents as a function of the node voltages, and then the node voltages become the unknowns in the system of variables we need to solve.